# How a middleware is deployed for a distributed system?

Tags: architecture, distributed-computing, middleware, distributed-system

I studied about distributed systems but I'm still not understanding how a middleware is deployed in order to install a distributed system.

I practiced sockets, but didn't anything about middleware and distributed system development and administration.

I'm confused about how the middleware can be deployed - must it be installed on a proxy machine, or must be installed on every machine (as part of the distributed system)? How client machines make use of middleware, is there a client part of the middleware?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could tell this from a developer perspective. 
If you are working on a middleware integration project:

(1). You will be using a IDE like IBM Websphere Integration Designer(from IBM & built on top of eclipse).

(2). In this you will develop your flow, and suppose your flow has to connect to a System say A & System B, and you are sending some request to them and expecting some result to come back to your flow.

(3). You will use Web services(like SOAP) and hit to the port through which the Systems from another server are exposed and you will get back the result.

(4). You will have this inbuilt WAS server you will have in your IDE where you will deploy your integrated module. In this way, everything is connected via ports, urls and you are able to setup a distributed environment.

My answer not directly talks about distributed systems, I am much sharing my experience working in the Middleware Integration domain which is much of distributed computing.

Answer (score 2):

Many of the middleware integrations in enterprise level systems are based on the concept of Service oriented architecture(SOA).

In SOA,you are responsible to connect disparate systems into one functional integral unit. Web services act as a way of integrating the different systems. Many of the Web applications use REST but still there are many enterprises which expose there services through SOAP(due to better security standards).

**Simple example:** Suppose you are building a web management system for a bank say. There are many operations involved: you need to handle creating customers, financial transactions,managing customers. You don't have to create every design from scratch. You can leverage some operations.Like suppose creating customer , functionality already available in c# and you want to use the same logic in your java code let us say. Than you need to use Web services.
This was just to explain you how distributed pattern works in SOA.

Further, there will be many server end configuration like JMS(Java messaging service), MQ's which play a crucial role in integration.

I suggest you to read about these, this could provide you some picture over the clarifications you need.

**Edited:**

[image: SOA Imagined]

Think of the system-1 has a Client like Web Browser

system-2 you can see that is connected to various sub units. System 2 is your entire app which you have built by reusing the functionalities through the sub units connected.

http request/response you are able to send back and forth information between client and server.

Through Web Services you are able to connect to any sub system in a platform independent way to build whatever you need by leveraging already existing functions from them.

MQ's you use for data storage while routing/message transformation in the flows.

Comment: thanks for the explanation. If I understand correctly the example - the **middleware** is MQ and the c#/java codes are the **apps**?

Comment: I understood the concept of SOA, but I need to know some examples about middleware *deployment*. Shall it be installed on every machine in order to implement the SOA architecture, could you give an example of a middleware?

Comment: You would deploy the middleware solutions in Servers. There are many vendors available in the market like IBM provides with IBM Websphere Application Server(WAS), Oracles Service Bus etc.

Comment: ok, then let's say I have WAS, and two separate server machines (A and B) each one running a different application written under different programming language, and I need to unify the access to the apps - Should WAS be installed standalone on a separate machine (C) connecting externally with A and B?

Comment: @Kais I have added a new answer since my comment was too long.